# 3D identity matrix to correctly set vertices

Tags: c, matrix, 3d

Im playing around with matrices, with a view to doing 3D transformation in GDI (for the fun of it). At the moment i'm checking that im getting the right values from identity matrix given a representation of four vertices arranged in a square. I've been scratching my head as to why it's not giving expected output. I have done my research but can't see what i am doing wrong here.

Here's my definition of matrix.

```
typedef struct m{
    float _m01, _m05, _m09, _m13;
    float _m02, _m06, _m10, _m14;
    float _m03, _m07, _m11, _m15;
    float _m04, _m08, _m12, _m16;
}mat;

struct m matIdentity(struct m *m1){
   m1->_m01 = 1.0; m1->_m05 = 0.0; m1->_m09 = 0.0; m1->_m13 = 0.0;
   m1->_m02 = 0.0; m1->_m06 = 1.0; m1->_m10 = 0.0; m1->_m14 = 0.0;
   m1->_m03 = 0.0; m1->_m07 = 0.0; m1->_m11 = 1.0; m1->_m15 = 0.0;
   m1->_m04 = 0.0; m1->_m08 = 0.0; m1->_m12 = 0.0; m1->_m16 = 1.0;
}
```

Here's making use of matrix with

```
 struct m matrix;
 matIdentity(&matrix);

//represent 4 vertices(x,y,z,w);

float square[4][4] = {
        {0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {0.0, 20.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 1.0},
        {20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
    };

           float result[4][4];

           int i = 0;
           for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
           result[i][1] = (matrix._m01 * square[i][0]) + (matrix._m05 * square[i][1]) +    (matrix._m09 * square[i][2]) + (matrix._m13 * square[i][3]);
           result[i][2] = (matrix._m02 * square[i][0]) + (matrix._m06 * square[i][1]) + (matrix._m10 * square[i][2]) + (matrix._m14 * square[i][3]);
           result[i][3] = (matrix._m03 * square[i][0]) + (matrix._m07 * square[i][1]) + (matrix._m11 * square[i][2]) + (matrix._m15 * square[i][3]);
           result[i][4] = (matrix._m04 * square[i][0]) + (matrix._m08 * square[i][1]) + (matrix._m12 * square[i][2]) + (matrix._m16 * square[i][3]);
           }


 char strOutput[500];
           sprintf(strOutput,"%f %f %f %f\n %f %f %f %f\n %f %f %f %f\n %f %f %f %f\n ", 
           result[0][0], result[0][1], result[0][2], result[0][3],
           result[1][0], result[1][1], result[1][2], result[1][3],
           result[2][0], result[2][1], result[2][2], result[2][3],
           result[3][0], result[3][1], result[3][2], result[3][3]
           );
```

I have a feeling the problem is somewhere to do with multiplying a row based representation of vertices using a column major matrix. Can anyone please suggest how i should be doing this.

Comment: You have a major bug by setting result[i][1..4].  As you do in the sprintf, you should be using result[i][0..3].  Other than that, vbmaster is right - why is your matrix struct not an array, while your square matrix to play with is?  And what you have is ok if you're only ever doing a 4x4 matrix, but it would be a good exercise in matrices to make it generic for any size.

Comment: Ah ha! Now you point that out i see it. I thought having the matrix as a struct might make it more manageable to pass the matrix to other functions within the program rather than using an array. Although the 'play values' are currently in an array, i had planned to incorporate these values within a struct with other variables that describe what the 3D representation is, for example. Is it totally an incorrect idea to use structs here? I mean, is there a performance problem here concerning structs or is it just that arrays are a more direct type for this situation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Typical matrix construction is to put the arrays in a struct.  You've got the right idea in adding other information to the matrix (though even in C, you can do some good object oriented practices like clear separations of data - make sure what you add to the matrix struct is appropriate for a matrix.  For a 3d representation, make a different struct that includes a matrix.)  The big thing with arrays is that they make your code neater, and iterating simple, and once you get into dynamic memory, you can make them any size, so a 2x2 acts just like a 56x56 matrix.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't understand why you don't use array first, then start to use array and iteration, and in the end give up iteration. Please, such program can only cause confusion.
2. The correct formula is `C(i, j)=sigma(A(i, k)*B(k, j), k=1..n)`, where C=AB and n is 4 for your case.
   (e.g., this line should be like: `result[i][0] = (matrix._m01 * square[0][i]) + (matrix._m02 * square[1][i]) + (matrix._m03 * square[2][i]) + (matrix._m04 * square[3][i]);` )Write a simple nested for-iteration to calculate this...
3. This is not for one vector, but n vectors....

Answer (score 0):

This is not matrix multiplication. Multiplying a vector by a matrix goes like this:

```
float mat[4][4];
float vec_in[4];
float vec_out[4];
// todo: initialize values
for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
{
    vec_out[j] = 0.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        vec_out[j] += vec_in[i] * mat[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the mat[4][4] a column order or row order matrix? This is what i have difficuly in seeing. Thats why i had separate _m12, _m16 etc. floats in my struct declaration, so i could see which is which clearly. Isn't that a clearer way to visualise the matrix mathematically. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Assume the 1st index is the row, the 2nd is the column. In the notation that is common in computer graphics, the vector is a row vector, and the matrix is multiplied from the right (v x M). This convention may be different in math textbooks; at least in German text books column vectors and multiplication from left (M x v) are more common.

Although quite old, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206269%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is still a good read, IMHO.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was using OpenGL redbook to get the maths. It has column first, then row, so it caused a few moments of confusion. The sylvester.js library actually helped to realise i had initially had the matrix the wrong way